# Getting 'Selected scheme "iosApp" does not support "iphonesimulator"' error for Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: xcode, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to run the [initial example apps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-create-first-app.html#run-your-application-on-android) generated by the Kotlin Multi Platform Mobile plugin in Android Studio.  I followed [these steps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-setup.html) for my environment setup. The Android Simulator runs correctly, but the iPhone Simulator does not.  The Run Configuration has the following error:

```
Error: Selected scheme "iosApp" does not support "iphonesimulator"
```

When I run the configuration (ignoring the error), the iPhone simulator does open and appears to load iOS, but it never loads the "Hello, iOS" application that is in Android Studio.

What would cause this?

Version Information:

- macOS 12.2.1
- Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 2
- Xcode 13.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it with the following method.

- Please close the Android Studio.
- Go to ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ folder and delete `com.jetbrains.AppCode.BridgeService.plist` there.
- Launch Android Studio with the KMM plugin again. It should work now.

Comment: It doesn't help me, unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me as well. @DenisSologub did you managed to find any other solution to this problem?

Comment: @Adrian Invalidate cache and restart studio but I wouldn’t call it “solution”. I have opened a ticket in JetBrains, I hope they will fix soon.

Comment: doesn't help for me either on M1 mac :-/

Comment: The build step did finish ok for me and produced iosApp.app. The launch step failed. So, I made a simple script to install it from Terminal (M1 Mac). `xcrun simctl install 'iPhone 8 Plus' iosApp.app`  To launch it, `xcrun simctl launch 'iPhone 8 Plus' orgIdentifier.iosApp` (note that orgIdentifier is not a placeholder... you need the actual string)

Answer (score 0):

From my tests, it seems that there may be multiple reasons for which we receive this error:

- the root folder of the ios project has a different name than the .xcodeproject file. Sometimes it works even if they are different and maybe it matters if we change this name after the frameworks was already connected to the iOS project.
- "Other linker flags" were manually copied and they were not copied using the copy button from the [Connect the framework to your iOS project](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-integrate-in-existing-app.html#connect-the-framework-to-your-ios-project). This results to wrong data like:

```
   "$(inherited)", 
   "-framework", 
   "shared\n",
```

instead of

```
    "$(inherited)",
    "-framework",
    shared,
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by going into `Edit Configurations` on Android Studio and choosing the location of my XCode project file again. I believe this is an error of the KMM plugin in Android Studio and has yet to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Updating Android Studio and KMM plugin worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).